# CakePHP 2.2.4 reCAPTCHA validation not working

Tags: cakephp, recaptcha

Hello I have a signup system working in cakePHP 2.2.4 [signup](http://www.androtutorials.com/Users/signup) the reCAPTCHA I'm using from this link [Jahdrien/ReCaptcha-Plugin](https://github.com/Jahdrien/ReCaptcha-Plugin)  is showing on my view but the validation of the codes is not working please can someone tell me how to do the reCAPTCHA validation?

UsersController.php // My Cotroller.

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController{
    public $components = array('Recaptcha.Recaptcha');
    public $helpers = array('Recaptcha.Recaptcha');
    public function signup(){

        $d = $this->request->data;
        $d['User']['id'] = null;
        if(!empty($d['User']['password'])){
                $d['User']['password'] = Security::hash($d['User']['password'],null,true);  
        }
        if($this->User->save($d,true,array('username','password','email'))){
            $link = array('controller'=>'Users','action'=>'activate',$this->User->id.'-'.md5($d['User']['password']));
            App::uses('CakeEmail','Network/Email');
            $mail = new CakeEmail();
            $mail->from('noreplay@localhost.com')
                 ->to($d['User']['email'])
                 ->subject('CakePHP Test :: Registration on Ohyeahhh.com')
                 ->emailFormat('html')
                 ->template('signup')
                 ->viewVars(array('username'=>$d['User']['username'],'link'=>$link))
                 ->send();
                 $this->request->data = array();
            $this->Session->setFlash("Your account was successfully created.","notif",array('type'=>'Success'));
        }else{
            $this->Session->setFlash("Please correct the following errors.","notif");
        }

    }
?>
```

User.php // My Model.

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel{
    public $validate = array(
        'username'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'message'=>'Invalide Username!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                'message' => 'Username has to be more than 3 chars'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Username already taken!'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
                array(
                    'rule' => 'alphaNumeric',
                    'allowEmpty'=>false,
                    'message' => 'Password must be AlphaNumeric!'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule' => array('minLength', '4'),
                    'message' => 'Username has to be more that 3 chars'
                ),
                array(
                    'rule' => array('confirmPassword', 'password'),
                    'message' => 'Passwords do not match'
                )), 
        'confirmpassword' => array(
                            'rule' => 'alphanumeric'
        ),
        'email'=>array(
            array(
                'rule'=>'email',
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'required'=>true,
                'message'=>'Invalide mail adress!'
            ),
            array(
                'rule'=>'isUnique',
                'message'=>'Mail adress already taken!'
            )
        )
    );
    function confirmPassword($data)
    {
        if ($data['password'] == Security::hash($this->data['User']['confirmpassword'],null,true)) {
            return true;
        }
            return false;
    }
}
?>
```

signup.ctp // My view.

```
<?php 

echo $this->Session->flash();
echo $this->Form->create('User');   
echo $this->Form->input('username' ,array('label'=>"Username :")); 
echo $this->Form->input('password' ,array('label'=>"Password :")); 
echo $this->Form->input('confirmpassword' ,array('label'=>"Password (type again to catch typos) :", 'type' => 'password')); 
echo $this->Form->input('email' ,array('label'=>"Email :"));  
echo $this->Recaptcha->show(array(
                'theme' => 'red',
                'lang' => 'en',
            ));
echo $this->Recaptcha->error();
echo $this->Form->end('Register'); 
?>
```

The Recaptcha folder is in my "root/plugin/" folder.

This is the ValidationBehavior.php that I don't know how to use to make the validation working.

```
<?php
class ValidationBehavior extends ModelBehavior {
    function beforeValidate(&$model) {
        die(' probando funcion de validacion ');
        $model->validate['recaptcha_response_field'] = array(
            'checkRecaptcha' => array(
                'rule' => array('checkRecaptcha', 'recaptcha_challenge_field'),
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'You did not enter the words correctly. Please try again.',
            ),
        );
    }

    function checkRecaptcha(&$model, $data, $target) {
        App::import('Vendor', 'RecaptchaPlugin.recaptchalib');
        Configure::load('RecaptchaPlugin.key');
        $privatekey = Configure::read('Recaptcha.Private');
        $res = recaptcha_check_answer(
            $privatekey,                            $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
            $model->data[$model->alias][$target],   $data['recaptcha_response_field']
        );
        return $res->is_valid;
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly try ours.

https://github.com/CakeDC/recaptcha

It's united tested and documented. The one you're using is actually not really well done.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer I used the reCAPTCHA in the link you gave me, now the recaptcha is showing but I'm getting the following error while validating it : "Error: Call to a member function verify() on a non-object File: /home/sites/androtutorials.com/public_html/app/Controller/UsersController.php
Line: 7" I'm probably missing this line "Controllers that will be using recaptcha require the Recaptcha Component to be included. " I don't know how to include the Component. Any idea please about this please ? Thanks

Comment: burzum, Im following your tutorial but now it looks like the RecaptchaComponent.php  isnt working. I am getting this error Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function attach() on a non-object
File: /.../Controller/Component/RecaptchaComponent.php
Line: 120

Comment: Hey, I'm using CakeDC recaptcha too, and I just have a small question: is there a way to have recaptcha validation being made in the model instead of the controller as stated in https://github.com/CakeDC/recaptcha/blob/master/Docs/Documentation/Setup.md ?

Comment: The reason its done in the component is because it works with the request object. Some of the code could be probably moved into the model. See https://github.com/CakeDC/recaptcha/blob/master/Controller/Component/RecaptchaComponent.php#L145 I'm no longer working for the CakeDC. Create an issue on their Github page and ask if somebody would like to refactor it a little.

Answer (score 0):

Using CakeDC recaptcha is a good solution. Just implemented it without issues. If you getting an error it is probably because the plugin is not being loaded. Make sure that all files are placed in the Plugin\Recaptcha directory and you have following line added to the bootstrap.php:

CakePlugin::load('Recaptcha');